# I want to combine live revenue data from another sheet onto my sheet, matching according to ID on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have separate two sheets (let's call them Sheet AA and Sheet BB).

Sheet AA is for a particular type of items whereas Sheet BB is an inventory of everything. The items on Sheet AA have the same ID as they do on Sheet BB.

I'm trying to insert the total revenue column from Sheet BB into Sheet AA so that the new revenue column will update alongside Sheet BB as revenues change, matching by the item ID.
I'm having trouble with writing the matching part, and also confused as to whether I should use VLOOKUP or QUERY, etc with IMPORTRANGE after looking at other guides. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you're working on (free of sensitive information), including the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with: =VLOOKUP(cell# I want to match with, IMPORTRANGE("URL","SheetName",Cells"), column I wanted the data from, FALSE)

Answer (score 0):

Are these sheets in the same Google Spreadsheet or are they in separate Spreadsheets? If both sheets are in the same Spreadsheet file you could probably do this with a sumif formula. For example, if the id is in column A of AA and quantity is in column B of AA the formula in BB to match column A in BB would be `=sumif(AA!A$2:A24,A2,AA!B$2:B)`

Comment: *"They're on separate spreadsheets"*. In that case use the `IMPORTRANGE` function. If still in need share a test sheet.

Comment: If they are in separate spreadsheets, create a new sheet in the same spreadsheet as sheet BB and importrange the entire AA sheet into that sheet. Then perform the calcs on the imported sheet.

Comment: @user3511512 thank you for the guidance :D figured it out